# How to enter gnupg-agent key passhprase from CLI?

Tags: gnupg

I do sign commits with git, and it's a big problem that I can't enter gpg key passphprase from anywhere except CLI. If I'll do commit in vscode for example, it will fail. So I've came up with idea to just simply input passphrase from CLI, and cache it for some period of time.

I'm using fish shell in here so here's a config:

```
set -x GPG_TTY (tty)
eval (gpg-agent --daemon --allow-preset-passphrase  --default-cache-ttl 43200)
```

As I understand I need to enable to preset the passhprase for the agent. So now what's next?

I've tried to preset a key like this, but it fails:

```
$ echo mypassphrase | /usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -c E2AB66331DA5CA780B7B1FA5D4BF11DA1E39EDFF

gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Not supported
```

I've googled everything I could, but no one is answering this question anywhere. Would be nice to have something like `ssh-add`, you just add a private key, and enter password, wonder why gpg-agent  haven't adopted this nice design.

Answer (score 9):

Seems to be solved. There's a need to add couple of things to `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`:

```
default-cache-ttl 46000
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-gtk-2
allow-preset-passphrase
```

Reload gpg-agent

```
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

Comment: did you have to manually create the conf file.  i don't actually see such a file after starting gpg-agent